# SQL - Return The Greater of a Partition

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning

I have the following table -

[image]

My goal is to return the Company/ID row with the highest "count" respective to a partition done by the ID.

So the ***expected output*** should look like this :

[image: My code]

My current code returns a count partitioned on **all** ids. I just want it to return the one with the highest count.

Current code -

```
select distinct Company, Id, count(*) over (partition by ID)
from table1
where company in ("Facebook","Apple")
```

My output:

[image]

Comment: You can use what you wrote as a subquery, then partition that by Company to get the max.

Comment: Hi, can you please post what this would look like? @Barmar

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql?rq=1

Comment: So I would need to use 2 partitions? The link provided does not have 2 partitions? Not sure how that would look like.. @Barmar

Comment: If we add one row with Facebook 555, then the ID 555 is the most occurring ID and you only want to output its rows (and not have Apple 123 in your results any longer). Is this correct?

Comment: Hi, no it should be with each company/id in mind @ThorstenKettner. In other words, it would apply to per company/id combination, and then the id that occurs greater times is what gets returned

Comment: On a side note: Double quotes are meant for names / aliases in SQL. Use single quotes for string iterals: `where company in ('Facebook','Apple')`.

Comment: And next time [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here along with an aggregation query:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Company, ID, COUNT(*) AS Count,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY Company, ID
)

SELECT Company, ID, Count
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Here is a running [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8284ca81db79fb89f176d27ff6bedde5) for MySQL.

Comment: Yes, impressive. It's mind reading even, because you asked for the IDs with the highest overall counts and even added a query to support this statement, when you actually wanted the IDs with the highest count per company, which you clarified in the request comments *after* Tim wrote this query :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your base query is incorrect. You partition by ID regardless of the company, but in your request comments you clarify that you want to count per ID and company. This would have to be

```
select distinct company, id, count(*) over (partition by company, id)
from table1
where company in ('Facebook','Apple');
```

But that query boils down to be a mere aggregation and doesn't need window functions at all. It is evaluating the count for each single row, only to dismiss duplicates later with `DISTINCT`. `DISTINCT` is a costly operation, so why not simply aggregate your rows in the first place?

```
select company, id, count(*)
from table1
where company in ('Facebook','Apple')
group by company, id;
```

Now you only want to keep the rows with the highest count per company, and this is where window functions come into play:

```
select  company, id, total
from
(
  select
    company,
    id,
    count(*) as total,
    max(count(*)) over (partition by company) as max_total
  from table1
  where company in ('Facebook','Apple')
  group by company, id
) aggregated
where total = max_total;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT company, id, COUNT(*)
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, COMM, DEPTNO
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This query doesn't report the companies/ids with the highest counts, but includes all with a count greater than one. This is not desired.